# Dispatch Queues for Asynchronous Web Service Call

Tags: facebook-graph-api, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I'm calling the Facebook Graph API to get the email, facebook ID and name of a user that logs into my app through Facebook.

I  successfully get the information; I'm now trying to use dispatch groups so the function that call graph waits until the graph API call completes before returning. The graph request is asynchronous.

I can't figure out why this code is locking up.

1) Create a dispatch group

2) Enter said display group

3) Leave the group once info is retrieved or an error is found

4) Wait for the group leave before returning

It seems like my dispatch group enter is not called correctly but I can't figure out why.

```
class func getFBInformation()->Bool {
    var fbResult = false

    let fbGraphGroup = DispatchGroup()

    fbGraphGroup.enter()

    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]).start { (connection, result, err) in
        if err != nil {
            fbResult = false
            print("Pre Error Signal")
            fbGraphGroup.leave()
            return
        }

        if let resultDict = result as? [String:AnyObject] {
            <Do things with graph results>

            print("Pre success signal")
            fbResult = true
            fbGraphGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    fbGraphGroup.wait()
    print("Post signal")

    return fbResult
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How could it work?
First you enter the group, next you are waiting on main thread for completion handler until it leave the group. But the completion handler is not able to execute on the main thread to be able to leave the group.

As far as I know, your completion handler is dispatched on the main queue by the API. It is not necessary to use any other kind of synchronization.